# making an object move without cocos2d?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make a button move in my application without having to implement the cocos2d framework in my application. I am making a data application and dont want to add any other game elements except for a button that moves. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: In what sense do you want it to move? You can always access the button's `frame` and set it manually if that is all you need.

Comment: can you tell me how you mean to do that? i want it to move in and out on a given x axis without any y displacemnt.

Answer (score 2):

To move any object you simply have to give it a new frame by setting

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, width, height );
```

You can even easily have the phone animate it for you without any added frameworks by wrapping it with [UIView beginAnimation...] blocks.

Here's an example:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"moveButton" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

someButton.frame = CGRectMake( newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight );

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: if you can get away with targeting only iOS 4, use blocks! so much more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

You can move a view directly using

```
[theview setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
```

or you can use animations to do so a in cooler way (this should be the iOS 4.x Way)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{ [theview setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                         [self iAmDoneAnimatingNowICanDoSomethingElse]; }];
```